# 4 bit magnitude comparator VHDL

Tags: vhdl, comparator, magnitude

I have to make a 4bit magnitude comparator in VHDL with only concurrent statements (no if/else or case/when).

```
library IEEE;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;

entity Exercise is
port (  A : in std_logic_vector (3 downto 0);
        B : in std_logic_vector (3 downto 0);
        Ag : out std_logic;
        Bg : out std_logic;
        AeqB: out std_logic
       );   
end Exercise;

architecture Comparator of Exercise is

begin
    Ag <= '1'when (A>B) else '0'; 
    Bg <= '1' when (B>A) else '0';  --Problem: Here if i sumulate B="ZZZZ", Bg is 1, asi if B>A 
    AeqB<= '1' when (A=B) else '0'; 
end Comparator;
```

The problem is that i need to take in count all the other values of std_logic (U,X,Z,W,L,H,-), i know there is the `others` but cant figure it out how to make the comparator with `with/select` statement.

Thanks

Comment: If your definition of magnitude is the usual arithmetic one, then you would be better using numeric_std which will treat your vectors as numeric data. You then have to decide whether they are signed or unsigned numbers, and declare them as `signed` or `unsigned` respectively (or perform type conversions to the appropriate form).

Comment: Generally a std_logic_vector  can be considered unsigned by using package numeric_std_unsigned (-2008), which uses numeric_std calls with type conversions to unsigned for various operators including relational operators. This is a collision between meta values and binary values which numeric_std resolves as FALSE if either operand contains meta values. The default operators (IEEE Std 1076-2008 9.2.3 Relational operators in this case) are pure positional - order in the enumerated std_ulogic type definition, and 'Z' has a higher position than '1' or '0'.

Comment: VHDL2008 support is still lacking in many tools, including Xilinx, so you may not want to use numeric_std_unsigned just yet.

Answer (score 0):

In general you can 'convert' the various values that std_logic can take into either `0` or `1` using the `to_01` function. I think it's in package `numeric_std`.

Answer (score 0):

```
library IEEE;

    use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;
    use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_ARITH.ALL;
    use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_UNSIGNED.ALL;

    entity comp_4 is
    port (  A:IN STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(0 to 3);
        B:IN STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(0 to 3);
        ET:OUT STD_LOGIC;
        GT:OUT STD_LOGIC;
        LT:OUT STD_LOGIC);

    end comp_4;

    architecture dataflow of comp_4 is

    begin
    with A-B(0 to 3) select

    ET <=   '1' when "0000",
        '0' when others;

    with A > B select

    GT <=   '1' when true,
        '0' when others;

    with A < B select

    LT <=   '1' when true,
        '0' when others;

    end dataflow;
```

Comment: The code I have written is trying to model a 4 bit comparator using the with - select - when statement. The entity definition is pretty straightforward.